# cocoa and objective c save, edit and load files

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

hello I am trying to create a text file that will then store some data

```
- (IBAction)saveUser:(id)sender{
   NSString *name = [nameField stringValue];
   NSString *weight = [weightField stringValue];
   NSDate *date = [datePick dateValue];

}
```

I want to be able to create a file that stores the following information and uses the name field as the name of the file.  I also want to be able to load the file and read that data from it

Any help is appreciated 
Thanking You

Comment: If you are looking for just storing data, then you can use coredata for storing it, rather than storing it into text file

Comment: Also please edit your title in a meaningful way.. **Cocoa and objective C** doesn't help anyone

Comment: Refer this link [http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Read-and-Write-to-Files-with-IOS-5-SDK-Objective-C-iPad-iPhone-iPod-Touch](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Read-and-Write-to-Files-with-IOS-5-SDK-Objective-C-iPad-iPhone-iPod-Touch) It is nice tutorial on saving/reading text files in Documents Directory. Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple. But you might want to look into NSMutableDictionary instead. Both NSString and Dictionary have methods writeToFile:@"filename.txt".

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:[nameField stringValue] forKey:@"name"];
[dict setValue:[weightField stringValue] forKey:@"weight"];
[dict setValue:date forKey:@"date"];

[dict writeToFile:name atomically:YES];
```

you read from the file the same way,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:name];
```

As simple as it gets

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get some informations from class NSFileManager, such as like this,

```
[fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:contentData attributes:NULL];
```

the contentData is NSData, and it includes the content of what you want to save, the filename is in filePath that you need to set.

Thanks!